# Joomla shows spam meta description?

Tags: php, joomla, metadata

The problem is that this site is showing the wrong meta description in Google search. I had the issue before and that was fixed by simply crawling the site again which took Google around 2.5 weeks. Anways this means the problem is coming back and so I need a better fix for it. I've already seen alot of topics simply saying to update my Joomla but since I didn't create the site I honestly don't know where to start.

I also tried looking at the Configuration.php file but that looks completely fine. The meta description in there is what it's supposed to be. Now I've also checked Global Configuration when I log in to the administration of the website and the meta tags there are also completely fine.

This is what the meta description is right now btw and what it's supposed to be.

**What the meta description is right now:**
*Welkom bij restaurant Don Comer. ... Welkom op de 36 hour cialis dosage website van ''Restaurant Don Comer''!*

**And it's supposed to be:** 
*Welkom bij restaurant Don Comer. ... Welkom op de website van ''Restaurant Don Comer''!*

The addres of the website is wwww.doncomer.nl if anyone needs it. Any help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would export your database to a .sql file then search this file for (or at least part of this string)

36 hour cialis dosage

Then if still no luck i would search the contents of all files for the same string.

Hopefully it will be there somewhere. Postback once you have done this.

Comment: I'm currently going through setting up Apache, PHP and MySQL so it's gonna take a while but once that's done I'll get back to you.